# How to pass an SVG file from a views function to a template?

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, svg

Within my views.py file I have a function that when called via a request, generates an .svg file. I then want this function to render the template and display said .svg file.

Code I have so far (simplified):

views:

```py
def home(request):
    # ---------------------------------------
    # generate test.svg file and save to a buffer
    # ---------------------------------------

    svg_data = open("buffer/test.svg", "rb").read()

    data = {
        'image': svg_data
        }

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', data)
```

template:

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<svg>
    {{ image }}
</svg>
{% endblock content %}
```

Unfortunately when I attempt to access the {{ image }} tag within the template, it displays nothing. So I ask, is there a way that I can load an .svg file in my views function and have it displayed within my template?

Comment: I think you have to use the safe filter or django would escape your svg {{ image|safe }}

Comment: @pfitzer I am afraid applying the safe filter does not seem to solve the issue. Still I thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If your SVG image is in a template folder, you can simply use:

```
<svg>
    {% include "buffer/test.svg" %}
</svg>
```

Or if the location of the file is somewhere other than your template directory, you can create a custom filter tag and use the tag.

```
@register.simple_tag
def include_anything(file_name):
    return open(file_name).read()
```

and then use `{% include_anything '/full/path/to/file.svg' %}`

[source](https://qr.ae/TWTmC6)

Answer (score 0):

I came across a same problem where when I had passed the `svg` as text to the django template, and it simply displayed the text as opposed to rendering it. The error turned out to be due to the `svg` text itself being rendered as a string.

If you check your HTML console you should be able to see that the `svg` text will be *stringified*.

The easiest way I solved it is with the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter, e.g.,

```
{{ svg_data|safe}}
```

In the case of the OP it should have worked with

```
{{ image|safe }}
```